# React Data Table Child Rows missing event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, event-listener

I am using a datatable using the React library. The datatable I am using has expandable rows and upon clicking it formats the child row which is another table.

Once the child table is created I use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add a data toggle to the child table headers. However, once I click the toggle nothing happens. When viewing in chrome I do not see the click event listeners that allows the data-toggle to open.

How can I solve this issue?

```
table.on('click', '.parent-row td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);

  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
    tr.find('.icon-toggle-row').attr('class', 'icon icon-toggle-row collapsed').attr('aria-expanded', 'false'); //Handle Toggle Collapse
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(thisComponent.format(row.data()), "child-table").show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
    tr.find('.icon-toggle-row').attr('class', 'icon icon-toggle-row').attr('aria-expanded', 'true'); //Handle Toggle Expand
  }
});

format(rowData) {
  var childContainer = document.createElement('div');

  if (rowData.children == null) {
    return '<span>No child data</span>';
  }
  var subtable = ReactDOM.render(
    <Table autoWidth={false} columns={childColumns} data={rowData.children} />,
    childContainer
  );
  $(childContainer).find('table').find('th').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++) {
      if (metaData[i].Attrufn === this.textContent.trim()) {
        this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', metaData[i].MetaData);
        return;
      }
    }
  });

  return childContainer.innerHTML;
}
```

MetaData

```
public virtual string MetaData
{
    get { return " <span class=\"icon icon-information no-sort\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"right\" title=\"\" data-original-title=" + string.Format("\"{0}\"", Attrdef) + "></span>"; }
}
```

Comment: We need to see `metaData`. How are elements with `.parent-row td.details-control` added to the page? My first guess is that you are hoping your click event at the top there will bind to all the elements with a class of `.parent-row td.details-control`, but they are created dynamically, after the page loads. If they are created dynamically you have to bind an event to them after they are on the page.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin The parent rows also use the Table component and the columns are specified before that. The data is being filled through an ajax request. Yes  that was my hop that my click events on the parent elements would also work for the children. But the children is dynamically created using the data stored. I have added the MetaData above. Can you show me an example of how I would bind an event to the children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your goal, simply put, you should turn `childColumns` or `rowData.children`, which ever is the reference to that table's children, into React components. Then house the `onClick` event in that child component.

```
export default class TableChild extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    // construct state;
  }
  onClick = (event) => {
    // do stuff on click
    console.log(event)
  }
  render() {
    const { rowData } = this.props
    return <tr onClick={this.onClick}>{rowData}</tr>
  }
}

export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    // construct state;
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    return (
      <table id="parentTable">
        { data && data.forEach(childData => {
          <TableChild rowData={childData} />
        })}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. After opening the child row add this line of code:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]',tr.next('tr')).tooltip();
```